# Git - how to move master branch to other branch and head

Tags: git

Im doing for fun exercises on learnbranching. But im stuck on one of goals.

I have to move 'master' from one branch to another and force to move 'bugFix' to C0.
[starting point of exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnWoI.png)

I do get almost similiar effect, to goal where one branch is faded after:

```
git branch -f
```

then

```
git branch -f master HEAD~2
```

How to move master, to C6 then?

[goal on the left and my situation on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjvT5.png)

I think I know how to do the rest. When I'll find how to move master then I have to do only:

```
git checkout bugFix
git branch -f bugFix HEAD~3
git checkout C1
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I have found the solution.

1st

```
git branch -f master C6
```

Then

```
git branch -f bugFix C0
```

And last

```
git checkout C1
```

Yes! It was that easy :D

Comment: Hey there. I dont knwo learnbranching, and I wonder which is upstream. The arrows point upwards, but the commit numbers somehow indicate otherwise. In the starting point is C5 before C3 or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

But anyway I just read that the command `$ show solution` will help you out. (Read here: https://github.com/pcottle/learnGitBranching/issues/109#issuecomment-25773762)

But I guess: #spoileralarm...

Comment: Thank you. I think It will help me. I would give you +1 vote but since I don't have enough points they are not visible for the others :)